# Having trouble with the scanner object and where it is executed

Tags: java, math

Hey guys I have a question. I'm trying to write a pig dice game and I'm having trouble with the scanner portion of the program where I ask the user whether they want to continue playing the game or not. The program is supposed to ask the user y or n to play but I can't seem to get my program to read the user input on the correct line and relaying the user information to the program so my if/else statement can validate or invalidate it. The program isn't complete yet, I'm just trying to get this one problem fixed before I move on. Thanks for any help!

Here is the code, the section I'm having trouble with is the section called takeTurn.

```
import java.util.*;
public class PigDice {
// when a player reaches this number, they win
public static final int WINNING_SCORE = 50; 

public static final int DIE = 6; // sides on a die. 

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
    Random rand = new Random();

    String winner = playGame( keyboard, rand );
    System.out.println( winner + " wins!" );
}
public static String playGame( Scanner scanner, Random rand ) {

    int score1 = 0; // player 1's score 
    int score2 = 0; // player 2's score 

    // play till someone wins
    while ( score1 < WINNING_SCORE && score2 < WINNING_SCORE ) {
        score1 += takeTurn( scanner, rand, 1, score1 );
        System.out.println( "Player 1 score: " + score1 );
        System.out.println( "***************************" );
        if ( score1 < WINNING_SCORE ) {   
            score2 += takeTurn( scanner, rand, 2, score2 );
            System.out.println( "Player 2 score: " + score2 );
            System.out.println( "***************************" );
        }
    }
    if ( score1 >= WINNING_SCORE ) {
        return "Player 1";
    }
    else {
        return "Player 2";
    }
}

public static int takeTurn( Scanner scanner, Random rand, int player, int score ) {
    int random = rand.nextInt(DIE)+ 1;
    System.out.println("Player " + player + " rolls: " + random);
    int firstRoll = random;
    int roundTotal = 0;
    String getAnswer = scanner.nextLine();

    if ( random > 1) {
        System.out.println( "Player " + player + " total for this round: " + firstRoll);
        roundTotal += firstRoll;
        System.out.print("Roll again? (y or n) : " + getAnswer);
        System.out.println();
        if ( "y".equalsIgnoreCase(getAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " rolls: " + random);

        }else if ( "n".equalsIgnoreCase(getAnswer)) {
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " rolls: " + random);
        } 
    }else {
        System.out.println("Player " + player + ": turn ends with no new points.");
        System.out.println("Player " + player + " score: " + score);
    }     


    return WINNING_SCORE;    
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the `scanner` statement `String getAnswer = scanner.nextLine();`

before asking the user to roll again question inside your `takeTurn()` method.

so put this statement after asking question to the user like below

```
 System.out.println("Roll again? (y or n) : ");

  String getAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
```

and also make sure you use `println` not just `print` while doing  `System.out.println("Roll again? (y or n) : ");`

`println` makes the user input to read from the new line whereas

`print` makes to read the input from the existing line itself along with your question to user.

Comment: He already declared getAnswer as a String before if/else. There's no need to re-declare getAnswer as a String anymore. It would end up getting error.

Comment: if we re declare then only the error comes but why he need to declare before if/else ? i suggested him to declare and assign directly inside  if ( random > 1) block..when we need that variable outside if block then only declaring it before if is good otherwise its best approach to declare inside if block only..